# Como colocar um código HTML em uma label no Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, label

Quando eu tento fazer isso:

```php
{{ Form::label("nomecampo", "Descrição<em>*</em>", array("class" => "entrada")) }}
```

A tag  entra dentro da tag  mas não é interpretada corretamente. Veja:

```html
<label class="entrada" for="nomecampo">Descrição<em>*</em></label>
```

Comment: Explique-se melhor. Até aora, o que eu pude entender, o Blade está funcionando como deveria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você deve usar o método HTML::decode() para tal fim, tente da seguinte forma:

```
{{ HTML::decode(Form::label("nomecampo", "Descrição<em>*</em>", array("class" => "entrada")) ) }};
```